# numpy.genfromtxt(), what is the difference between skiprows and skip_header?

Tags: python, numpy

I thought the `genfromtxt()` will skip `skip_header+skiprows`, but it is not. If the `skiprows` are active the `skip_header` is ignored.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skiprows` is just deprecated version of `skip_header`.
There is no difference between them.

See http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Remove-deprecated-skiprows-td28848.html